# Unset array elements based on conditions in php

Tags: php, arrays, nested

How should I go about to loop a nested array and unset elements based on multiple conditions? Beginning with the array below, the resulting array should contain only the elements where `period` equals "2" and `from` time is not the current day (ie should be tomorrow or later). The latter can be achieved by simply unsetting the first three elements in the `time` subarray since when `period` equals "2" and `from` is not before tomorrow is not possible to happen before the fourth element.

This is the original array:

```
array(2) {

    ["location"] => array(3){
        ["name"] => string(6) "Boston" 
        ["country"] => string(13) "United States" 
        ["timezone"] => array(1) { 
            ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                ["id"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" 
                ["utcoffsetMinutes"]=> string(4) "-300" 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    ["forecast"] => array(1) { 
        ["tabular"] => array(1) { 
            ["time"]=> array(9) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-08T16:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-08T19:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "2" 
                    }  
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "4.5" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }  
                } 

                [1]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-08T19:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T01:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "3" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.1" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 

                [2]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T01:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T07:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.3" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 

                [3]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T07:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T13:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "1" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.4" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 

                [4]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T13:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T19:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "2" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.4" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 

                [5]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T19:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T01:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "3" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.5" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Moderate breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 

                [6]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T01:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T01:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "6.0" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Moderate breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 
                [7]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T07:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T13:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "1" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.2" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 
                [8]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T13:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T19:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "2" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "3.9" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the resulting array when `period` equals "2" and `from` is tomorrow and later becomes

```
array(2) {

    ["location"] => array(3){
        ["name"] => string(6) "Boston" 
        ["country"] => string(13) "United States" 
        ["timezone"] => array(1) { 
            ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                ["id"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" 
                ["utcoffsetMinutes"]=> string(4) "-300" 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    ["forecast"] => array(1) { 
        ["tabular"] => array(1) { 
            ["time"]=> array(2) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T13:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-09T19:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "2" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "5.4" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 
                [1]=> array(2) { 
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
                        ["from"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T13:00:00" 
                        ["to"]=> string(19) "2015-02-10T19:00:00" 
                        ["period"]=> string(1) "2" 
                    }   
                    ["windSpeed"]=> array(1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { 
                            ["mps"]=> string(3) "3.9" 
                            ["name"]=> string(13) "Gentle breeze" 
                        } 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When working on loops you have to remember that unset() is a language construct and not a function and destroys the local variable. Your problem can be related to this fact, and you should post the code as well.  If you do unset inside in a foreach pass the value by reference foreach($array as &$x) .

Comment: Thanks. I need to keep the index values continous so shouldn't I use array_splice() instead of unset()?

Comment: you should show your code, or a simplified version of it